# кастомная обработка ошибки 404 в laravel 9 api

Tags: api, laravel-9

клиент - React SPA
в общем при попытке переопределить App\Exceptions\Handler как написано тут [например](https://laravel.su/docs/8.x/errors?ysclid=laicubkcsk817629013#rendering-exceptions)
ничего не меняется, все та же ошибка ngnix (прикрепляю)
по умолчанию получаю 404 ngnix ошибку без CORS заголовков - что не дает мне никак на клиенте обработать ответ

собственно вопрос:
как переопределить стандартную обработку 404 laravel? хочу JSON кастомный получить от api laravel
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в общем обошелся блоками try{....}catch{....} в контроллерах для findOrFail метода извлечения данных модели
с исключением ModelNotFoundException
Ни переопределить исключение в App\Exceptions\Handler
Ни кастомными исключениями согласно документации - не получилось
Вопрос остается открытым

Также вопрос - где вообще описаны встроенные исключения, можно ли их подменить собственными и как все это отдебажить - открыт.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял суть вопроса, но можно возвращать переопределенную любую ошибку с jsonoм
`return Response(json_encode(['message' => 'какое-то сообщение']), $status = 404, ['Content-Type' => 'string']);`

Comment: я не спорю.
я пытаюсь понять когда я переопределяю 
https://laravel.su/docs/8.x/errors?ysclid=laicubkcsk817629013#rendering-exceptions
в App\Exceptions\Handler

я вижу все ту же стандартную страницу ngnix